# Vuex setting variables in state from actions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

1. I am trying to populate the variable `onSale` in the state but not able to.
   I am getting my data from a json file. what is wrong with my code?
2. A separate question is sometimes I see the word 'context' instead of 'state', what is needed for and when to use it?

Thanks for help.

```js
state: {
  products: [],         
    onSale: [],
},
actions: {

  async fetchProducts({commit, state}) {
    axios.get('/src/assets/phones.json')
      .then(response => {
      commit('setProducts', response.data) //      setProducts(state, products) {
      // alert(response.data)
    })

    let allM = []
    await  state.products.map((d) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(d).length; i++) {
        if (d["onSale"])
          allM.push(d["onSale"])
          }
    })
    //alert(allM)
    //return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('setOnSale1', allM)
    //    alert(allM)

  })
},
mutations: {
  setOnSale1(state, onSale) {
    state.onSale = onSale
  },
},
```

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement in 1. What exactly does not work? Are there errors? The problem could be related to 2, or there could be something else. `context` is the object that has `state`, but also other things that you need in actions, mutations, etc - `commit`, `dispatch`, etc, otherwise you couldn't access them. The first argument is `context`, not `state`. It won't work correctly if you just call it `state`

Comment: Thanks Estus Flask, I am unable to populate onSale array in state, i tried to do so from action but getting empty response when trying to alert it.

Comment: Should be `setOnSale1({ state }` or `setOnSale1(context`. There are other problems, the promises needs to be straightforward and correct. That you tried to use `new Promise` (incorrect here) and `then` (not advisable with async/await) means that they need extra attention . Should be `await axios.get...` at least.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by :

```
    actions: {

         async fetchProducts({commit, state}) {
             await axios.get('/src/assets/phones.json')
                 .then(response => {
                     commit('setProducts', response.data) //      setProducts(state, products) {
                     // alert(response.data)
                 })

             let allM = []
             state.products.map((d) => {
                 for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(d).length; i++) {
                     // alert(d)
                     if (d["onSale"])
                         allM.push(d["onSale"])
                 }
             })
             commit('setOnSale1', allM[0])
         },

.............

 mutations: {
        setOnSale1(state, onSale) {
            state.onSale = onSale
        },

}
```